# Grafana Alert "connect: connection refused"

Tags: grafana, influxdb, telegraf, grafana-alerts

I can create a dashboard in grafana but when trying to create an alert, a connection refused error appears. Grafana can query influxdb as the dashboard can show results. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Grafana Alerts]